# Wanted: xsl:template that converts a node to its hexavigesimal value?

Tags: .net, xslt, hexavigesimal

I can almost here you say: "What the @##$# is a `hexavigesimal` value?"

> A hexavigesimal numeral system has a base of twenty-six.
>   Alternatively, base-26 may be represented using only letters of the
>   Latin alphabet. As there are 26 letters in English, base-26 is also
>   the highest base in which this is possible and hence utilizes every
>   letter. 0 is represented by A, 1 = B, 2 = C ... 24 = Y, 25 = Z. Some
>   examples: 26 = AA, 30 = BE

So it is basically what Excel uses a column description. I would like to have a function that converts a node with an int value into this value.

Source:

```
<root>
  <row>12</row>
  <column>23</column>
</root>
```

I would like to print `column` as `X` by calling a template that does the conversion. Can it be done?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT2.0, or just XSLT1.0?

Comment: I'm using the .Net 3.5 parser. I think that one is XSLT1.0

Comment: "basically" in the sense of "not quite", of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XSLT...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:variable name="symbols" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
   <xsl:variable name="symbols-count" select="string-length($symbols)" />
   <xsl:template match="row">
      <row>
      <xsl:call-template name="convert" />
      </row>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="convert">
      <xsl:param name="value" select="number(.)" />
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$value >= $symbols-count">
            <xsl:variable name="div" select="floor($value div $symbols-count)" />
            <xsl:variable name="remainder" select="$value - $div * $symbols-count" />
            <xsl:call-template name="convert">
               <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$div" />
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($symbols, $remainder + 1, 1)" />
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($symbols, $value + 1, 1)" />
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<root>
   <row>12</row>
   <column>23</column>
   <row>26</row>
   <column>23</column>
</root>
```

The following is output

```
<root>
  <row>M</row>
  <column>23</column>
  <row>BA</row>
  <column>23</column>
</root>
```

You should be able to adjust the **symbols** variable to allow any fancy-named-imal conversion. For example, to convert to hexadecimal change it to the following

```
<xsl:variable name="symbols" select="'0123456789ABCDEF'" />
```

And to binary

```
<xsl:variable name="symbols" select="'01'" />
```

Comment: Wow! Looks very good! Only think is that 26 will convert to `BA` instead of `AA`.

Comment: Hm, using `<xsl:value-of select="substring($symbols, $value , 1)" />` seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Well, in your question you do say `26 = BA`.... Because A = 0, then isn't BA correct for 26?

Comment: I see... it came from the quote :). Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You might find that `<xsl:number value="$n" format="A"/>` does what you want, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: The spec gives leeway for the processor to "localize" alphabetic numbering for example by adding accented letters to the sequence, or removing letters such as "i" and "o" that are potentially confusing. Also, this sequence goes X, Y, Z, AA, AB, whereas hexavigesimal with A=0 would go X, Y, Z, BA, BB, ...

Answer (score 0):

**In XSLT 1.0 use**:

```
 <xsl:template name="toHex">
   <xsl:param name="decimalNumber" />
   <xsl:if test="$decimalNumber >= 16">
     <xsl:call-template name="toHex">
       <xsl:with-param name="decimalNumber" 
              select="floor($decimalNumber div 16)" />
       </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select=
      "substring($hexDigits, ($decimalNumber mod 16) + 1, 1)" />
 </xsl:template>
```

where `$hexDigits` is the string `'0123456789ABCDEF'`.

**Here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="hexDigits" select="'0123456789ABCDEF'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:call-template name="toHex"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="toHex">
        <xsl:param name="decimalNumber" select="." />
        <xsl:if test="$decimalNumber >= 16">
            <xsl:call-template name="toHex">
                <xsl:with-param name="decimalNumber" select=
                  "floor($decimalNumber div 16)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select=
         "substring($hexDigits, ($decimalNumber mod 16) + 1, 1)" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this XSLT 1.0 transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<t>12345</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
3039
```

**See also my answer to this question**:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3053656/36305